# Which Prawn gems should I install for my rails app for creating a PDF?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, rubygems, prawn

Hi I have an app which needs to render a PDF with access to controller variables like in view, and ideally also allow me to use partials. Currently I just have installed:

```
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawn-table'
```

These work quite well, except for the fact that they do not allow for using partials.

After some reading I found some wrapper gems such as `prawn-rails`, `prawn_rails` (!) and `prawnto` or `prawnto_2`.

Does anyone have any experience with these gems and has a strong preference for any?

My Rails version: `Rails 4.2.4`